# Python, numpy and type hints: a tale of woe

Tags: python, numpy, types

I'm trying to write some basic Python code using numpy, and as someone who is pretty committed to the concept of strict type checking, I'm finding it a bit challenging.

I'm using VS Code with pylance, and my environment is somewhat version and library constrained.

One simple example:

```
flags = chi_squared > .5          # chi_squared is type np.ndarray
indices = chi_squared.argsort()
```

The first line is fine; no type warnings, the types of everything are known (even if flags is "Any").  The second line, however, gives me a type error because "the type of argsort() is partially unknown".

That's odd... but when I tracked down the numpy type stubs, I find that argsort is in fact partially undefined:

```
def argsort(self, axis=..., kind=..., order=...) -> typing.Any:
        'a.argsort(axis=-1, kind=None, order=None)\n\n    Returns the indices that would sort this array.\n\n    Refer to `numpy.argsort` for full documentation.\n\n    See Also\n    --------\n    numpy.argsort : equivalent function'
        ...
```

`axis`, `kind`, and `order` have no types (and returning Any is kind of lame as well... this function can really return any type?)

As a result, about half the lines in my code have cascading type errors like this, so my code is filled with `# type: ignore` directives.

I get that types in Python are a sort of bolt-on afterthought, and that libraries like numpy do some magical things, so I don't expect perfection, but I'm left wondering if there is a sane way to get the benefits of at least some type checking while using numpy, without littering my code with ignore statements.

What is the best way forward?

Comment: I haven't used typing, though I wrote one of the first SO answers about `numpy`s` use, which hadn't been developed at the time.  I think it's more useful when defining your own functions. Here `argsort` is a method, so the type of the `self` is already established.  The other arguments are `parameters`, things that you may use when writing the code, but probably won't be set by runtime variables.  Parameters like `axis` which may be `None` (the default), an integer, or a tuple, are common in `numpy`.  I don't think it's worth your while to type-check them.

Comment: You could also consider annotating the result types yourself, to avoid some of the cascading you describe. E.g., `indices: np.ndarray = chi_squared.argsort()`. I've also had success with [`nptyping`](https://pypi.org/project/nptyping/), but as @hpaulj pointed out, that was really only when adding type hints to new code I controlled.

Comment: With `indices = chi_squared.argsort()`, since you aren't providing any parameters, their documented types shouldn't matter.  According to the docs, `indices` will be `ndarray`, with `int` dtype.  Shape however depends on the shape of `chi_squared`.  In my experience getting dimensions right is the biggest debugging task (assuming you get past the obvious mistakes like wrong types - None, list, etc instead of array).  But I don't think typing helps much with shapes.